# 404 Not found error throws while click on custom module in admin interface in magento

Tags: magento

Config.xml file: 404 Error throws while click on link in admin interface. Help to sort out this issues.

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Chilly_RelProducts>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </Chilly_RelProducts>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <resources>
                <chilly_relproducts_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Chilly_RelProducts</module>
                        <class>Chilly_RelProducts_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                </chilly_relproducts_setup>
            </resources>
            <blocks>
                <relproducts>
                    <class>Chilly_RelProducts_Block</class>
                </relproducts>
            </blocks>
            <helpers>
                <relproducts>
                    <class>Chilly_RelProducts_Helper</class>
                </relproducts>
            </helpers>
            <models>
                <relproducts>
                    <class>Chilly_RelProducts_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>relproducts_resource</resourceModel>
                </relproducts>
                <relproducts_resource>
                    <class>Chilly_RelProducts_Model_Resource</class>
                    <entities>
                        <relproduct>
                            <table>relproducts_relproduct</table>
                        </relproduct>
                        <relproduct_store>
                            <table>relproducts_relproduct_store</table>
                        </relproduct_store>
                        <relproduct_product>
                            <table>relproducts_relproduct_product</table>
                        </relproduct_product>
                    </entities>
                </relproducts_resource>
            </models>
        </global>
        <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <chilly_relproducts>
                        <file>chilly_relproducts.xml</file>
                    </chilly_relproducts>
                </updates>
            </layout>
            <translate>
                <modules>
                    <Chilly_RelProducts>
                        <files>
                            <default>Chilly_RelProducts.csv</default>
                        </files>
                    </Chilly_RelProducts>
                </modules>
            </translate>
            <events>
                <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
                    <observers>
                        <relproduct>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>relproducts/adminhtml_observer</class>
                            <method>addRelproductBlock</method>
                        </relproduct>
                    </observers>
                </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
                <catalog_product_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <relproduct>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>relproducts/adminhtml_observer</class>
                            <method>saveRelproductData</method>
                        </relproduct>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_save_after>
            </events>
        </adminhtml>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Chilly_RelProducts before="Mage_Adminhtml">Chilly_RelProducts_Adminhtml</Chilly_RelProducts>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>
        <default>
            <relproducts>
            </relproducts>
        </default>
    </config>`

check the code and help to try to short out. It will working on the development server(local syste) not working in the production server.

Comment: What's the URL of the page your browser is trying to load when you get a 404?

Comment: are you want to create overwrite admin controller  ya create new admin controllers  for new module???